# Collecting exponentials

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Suppose you have expression that is a summation of products of exponentials, how to simplify it by collecting exponentials inside products?
See example what I need:

$$2^{\frac{x}{2}+5}*3^{\frac{1}{2}-2 x}*5^{x-2}+4^{3 x+2}*7^{3-2 x}*11^{4 x+\frac{1}{2}}=\\\frac{\left(32 \sqrt{3}\right)}{25} \left(\frac{5 \sqrt{2}}{9}\right)^x+5488 \sqrt{11} \left(\frac{937024}{49}\right)^x$$

```
2^(5+x/2)*3^(1/2-2 x)*5^(-2+x)+4^(2+3 x)*7^(3-2 x)*11^(1/2+4 x)==(32 Sqrt[3])/25 ((5 Sqrt[2])/9)^x+5488 Sqrt[11] (937024/49)^x
```

The output could be in the form:
$$\{\{\frac{\left(32 \sqrt{3}\right)}{25},\frac{5 \sqrt{2}}{9}\},\{5488 \sqrt{11},\frac{937024}{49}\}\}$$

because I can recover the result like this:

```
Total[#[[1]] #[[2]]^x&/@{{(32 Sqrt[3])/25 ,(5 Sqrt[2])/9},{5488 Sqrt[11] ,937024/49}}]==(32 Sqrt[3])/25 ((5 Sqrt[2])/9)^x+5488 Sqrt[11] (937024/49)^x
```

Comment: The starting expression is always an expanded sum of terms, each term being a product of exponentials as shown?

Comment: Yes, just sum of products of exponentials and nothing else. And exponential are just in one variable `x`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Log` to convert each term to a polynomial:

To handle cases where the sum is not expanded (e.g. `2(t1 + t2)` where `t1` and `t2` are exponential terms) and the expression may be a single term:

```
Simplify@Exp@CoefficientList[
   Log /@ Replace[
      Expand@expr,
      {e_Plus :> List @@ e, e_ :> {e}}] // 
    PowerExpand, x]
```

---

*Original case:* The input is always an expanded sum of
terms, each term being a product of exponentials shown in the OP.

```
expr = 2^(5 + x/2)*3^(1/2 - 2 x)*5^(-2 + x) + 
  4^(2 + 3 x)*7^(3 - 2 x)*11^(1/2 + 4 x);

Simplify@Exp@CoefficientList[Log /@ List @@ expr // PowerExpand, x]

(*  {{(32 Sqrt[3])/25, (5 Sqrt[2])/9}, {5488 Sqrt[11], 937024/49}}  *)
```

$$\left\{\frac {32 \sqrt {3}} {25}, \frac {5 \sqrt {2}} {9} \right\}, \left\{5488 \sqrt {11}, \frac {937024} {49} \right\}$$

*Response to comment:* To handle cases that are not sums but a single term (the expense of `Expand@expr` is probably very little if the term is already expanded, so I recommend the solution I put at the top).

```
Simplify@Exp@CoefficientList[
   Log /@ Replace[
      expr,
      {e_Plus :> List @@ e, e_ :> {e}}] // 
    PowerExpand, x]
```

Comment: Great trick with using logarithm! I will test it whether it works in all circumstances.

Comment: Sometimes the `Exp` return like `E^(2 (Log[3]+Log[17]))` for `expr=2^(2+4 x) 51^(2 x) 77^x+3^x`. And it does not work for `expr=3^(x+5)` or `expr=2*3^(x+5)` which are already in the required form, but I can handle all of that.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Try `Simplify[Exp@CoefficientList[...]]`. I guess it worked on the test example because there are certain autosimplify rules Mathematica applies right away. -- And if `expr` is not a *sum*, i.e., just a single term, then `List @@ expr` won't work properly.

Comment: There is another problem. For examples expr=2^s+3^s+51^(2 s)-3^(2 s) 289^s` produces `{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 2601}, {-1, 2601}}` but the desired result should be `{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}`. It is because of "hidden" zero: `51^(2 s)-3^(2 s) 289^s==0`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan This is the sort of issue I had in mind when I asked the question in the comment. The procedure might fail if the input is not prepared according to the requirements. You need to pass a sum of terms in the form you want process. In this case `Simplify[expr]` seems to fix the input.

Comment: I wanted to avoid `Simplify` in case for large `expr`, but it could be corrected afterwards by checking for repeated base of exponential and grouping them. Like with `{1, 3}, {1, 2601}, {-1, 2601}}` we have base `2601` twice, so we sum their multipliers, in this case `1+(-1)`. And then removing terms with zero multiplier.